# How to use selenium webdriver to extract numeric values from Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Here's the code containing the elements I need to test.

```
<div class="title ng-binding">     104 Alerts                        </div>
<ul role="menu">
<!-- ngRepeat: category in categories -->

<li class="ng-scope" role="menuitem" ng-click="showAlerts(category.name)" ng-repeat="category in categories" style="">
    <span class="cat-name ng-binding">conservation </span>
    <div class="count ng-binding">44</div>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: category in categories -->
<li class="ng-scope" role="menuitem" ng-click="showAlerts(category.name)" ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <span class="cat-name ng-binding">marketing </span>
    <div class="count ng-binding">3</div>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: category in categories -->
<li class="ng-scope" role="menuitem" ng-click="showAlerts(category.name)" ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <span class="cat-name ng-binding">outstanding delivery requirements </span>
    <div class="count ng-binding">34</div>
</li>
```

The top element tells us there are 104 Alerts total. Each element below is a certain type of alert. I need to pull out the values in all the alert subcategory elements(44, 3, 34), and Assert that they all add up to 104. Obviously in this case they do not.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you put your code that you have tried so that we can just give you a hint.

Comment: In my mind it's working something like... driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'conservation')]")).getAttribute("???"); But the "44" value is not within an attribute, so I don't know how to extract just the value "44"

Comment: why are you looking for the attribute of this xpath, The number that you are looking for is the `innerHTML` for the `div` element with `class = count ng-binding`?

Comment: Ok Let me give you a hint. First try to find all the elements with `class = count ng-binding` and store it in a `List<WebElement>`, then iterate on the list and fetch each value and add them.

Comment: Thanks. `List<WebElement>` seems like the most efficient way. For my purposes I just used `String elementval = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).getAttribute("innerHTML");`  for the alerts, then assert they equal the Total Alerts.

Comment: cool now I'll put the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see you need to find the numbers which is the `innerHtml` of all the `div` with `class = count ng-binding` so first you need to find all the elements with this class as below:-

```
int total = 0;
List<WebElement> totalDivs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='count ng-binding']"));
```

OR

```
List<WebElement> totalDivs = driver.findElements(By.className("count"));
```

Once you get all the `WebElements` then you need to iterate on them and add them out.

```
for(WebElement we : totalDivs){
    total += Integer.parseInt(we.getText());
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Output:-

```
81 // For this example.
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `count` and `ng-binding` are **two** different classes - it's a space-separated list. Your code can be improved by changing the selector to `By.className("count")`.

Comment: yep definitely it can be improved! :)